# WPF ScrollViewer is not appears in my Window after I add it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, scrollview

I have a MainWindow which includes 2 Dock Panels, a Grid (in the right Dock Panel) and inside of it some User Controls.
I want to add a ScrollViewer to appears in the right of my MainWindow, because I have a lot of content in each User Control.

When I'm add these 2 parameters to my XAML, I'm still didn't see the ScrollViewer appears, and I tried to write it under the Window, Grid, DockPanel, but nothing works.

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                    Height="700">
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Name="TextBlock_RegularUnit" Text="Regular Unit" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseEnter="TextBox_RegularUnit_MouseEnter"
                 MouseLeave="TextBox_RegularUnit_MouseLeave" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Name="DockPanel_UnitStatusReport" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:ManageUsers x:Name="ucManageUsers" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <local:RegularUnit x:Name="ucRegularUnit" Grid.Row="0" />
            <local:Actions x:Name="ucActions" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <local:HistoryTable x:Name="ucHistoryTable" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place ScrollViewer inside a Grid.It will make the ScrollViewer to use the available space within the Grid.

Layout like this,

```
<Grid>
     <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```